problem to align photos to create 3d model of teeth
I want to create a 3d model of an intraoral scan, e.g. teeth. I have tried a bunch of different software like Metashape, 3d Zaphyre, Adobe 3d Sampler, but it none of them worked sufficiently. I am a beginner, so any tips are highly appreciated. It seems that the problem already starts with aligning the images, probably due to the fact that not only the camera moves, but also the teeth as the object might move.
Thank you!
I have tried several different software and apps trying to generate a 3d scan, but the alignment did not work.
